# How to implement ASP.NET Core Identity framework's password hasher in java

Tags: java, c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I am working on a school project where we have an ASP.NET Core web application using Identity framework for our users (they can register and sign in) and we also have to develop a java application where we also have to register and sign in using the same user data as the ASP.NET Core application (mutual db). Our problem is that Identity hashes their passwords and to be able to sign in or register from our java application we have to compare hashes or hash the same way Identity does. I have been scanning the internet but haven't found a clear answer yet.

Now I understand ASP.NET Core Indentity v3 uses

> PBKDF2 with HMAC-SHA256, 128-bit salt, 256-bit subkey, 10000
> iterations

for hashing their passwords.

**My question is: what would be the best method of implementing the same hashing method in our java application? Is there a viable java library available that we can use to mimic the way Identity hashes their passwords? Or are there better approaches to solve this problem?**

Comment: If I understand correctly, you do not need to hash from your java application. You should simply expose an operation from your Identity application that uses [Usermanager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.verifypasswordasync?view=aspnetcore-5.0) to verify the password.

Comment: @Crowcoder Thank you for your answer! Maybe a stupid question but how do I expose an operation?

Comment: You would build controller actions that called methods on the UserManager. The java app would make HTTP calls to it.

Comment: @Crowcoder Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

you should just try to override the IPasswordHasher<> interface in the DI of the .net core app and use the same logic in the java app,
for reference you can look into this:
https://andrewlock.net/migrating-passwords-in-asp-net-core-identity-with-a-custom-passwordhasher/

one thing to consider, changing the way the hashing is done will make all your existing users locked out unless you migrate them, but since this is a school project i assume that its an acceptable outcome.

Comment: No, you shouldn't. If you do that on the client then it exposes the security internals to the user.

Comment: why would it expose the security internals to the user?
and what do you mean by that?

Comment: You cannot hash without a key, and you cannot hide a key from a user if it is running in their own process. These things must happen out of process on a secured resource, like a web server.

Comment: you do understand that you can debug your app with a debugger like jetbrains rider and view the default IPasswordHasher? 
i am taking into account that the app you are using which login and register a user is the web server, other wise you are doing something wrong. ( oh you are not the one asking the question sorry )

Comment: I'm assuming the java app is run interactively by the user, maybe that is a wrong assumption. Regardless, my point is that you cannot hide secrets from a user when those secrets are used in their own process. Sure, you can debug, the source code is not the issue, The issue is how you secure your secrets.

Comment: agreed secrets can not be saved on the client app, but this is a work for school my answer is how to get two apps to use the same hashing algorithm in the easiest manner, and with your help now he also knows that in production what not to do.